# Hide the first elements of a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have this div that displays this text

```
<address class="address address--tight">
      -17.7353231,-63.1696634, Av. Block, NY00, Miami, United States
</address>
```

How can I hide the first two elements (the coordinates) to only show the address, city and country

Comment: The coordinates are not elements, the whole string of text is one complete "element" (node, textNode te be precise). If you want to hide it, you will have to wrap it in something. If you are doing that, you might as well just not print it or remove it when you process the text. So you could do `address.textContent = address.textContent.split( ',' ).slice( 2 ).join( ',' )` to remove the first two "elements".

Answer (score 1):

Not possible without some JS/DOM. But ideally you should prepare the data before using it in DOM.

```js
const $address = document.querySelector('.address');
$address.textContent = $address.textContent.split(',').slice(2).join(',').trimLeft();
```

```html
<address class="address address--tight">
      -17.7353231,-63.1696634, Av. Block, NY00, Miami, United States
</address>
```

A regex version:

```js
const $address = document.querySelector('.address');
$address.textContent = $address.textContent.replace(/^[^,]+,[^,]+\s*,/, '');
```

```html
<address class="address address--tight">
      -17.7353231,-63.1696634, Av. Block, NY00, Miami, United States
</address>
```

But the fastest version could be:

```js
const $address = document.querySelector('.address');
const idx = $address.textContent.indexOf(',', $address.textContent.indexOf(',') + 1) + 1;
$address.textContent = $address.textContent.slice(idx).trimLeft();
```

```html
<address class="address address--tight">
      -17.7353231,-63.1696634, Av. Block, NY00, Miami, United States
</address>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let a = document.querySelector('.address').textContent;

let aTrim = a.substr(a.indexOf(", ")+2);

console.log(aTrim);
```

```html
<address class="address address--tight">
      -17.7353231,-63.1696634, Av. Block, NY00, Miami, United States
</address>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided, you can just take the `.textContent` of the element, `.split` it on `,`, remove the first two parts, then `.join` it back with `,`. This is highly specific though, and if you are not 100% you will always have this order and those details, this might fail.

```js
const address = document.querySelector( 'address' );

address.textContent = address.textContent.split( ',' ).slice( 2 ).join( ',' );
```

```html
<address class="address address--tight">
      -17.7353231,-63.1696634, Av. Block, NY00, Miami, United States
</address>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
const regexLat = /^(-?[1-8]?\d(?:\.\d{1,18})?|90(?:\.0{1,18})?)$/;
const regexLon = /^(-?(?:1[0-7]|[1-9])?\d(?:\.\d{1,18})?|180(?:\.0{1,18})?)$/;

let address = document.querySelector( 'address' ).textContent;
let split_address = address.split( ',' );
if(split_address.length > 2) {
    let lat = split_address[0];
    let lon = split_address[1];
    if(regexLat.test(lat) && regexLon.test(lon)) {
        address = split_address.slice( 2 ).join( ',' );
    }
}


<address class="address address--tight">
    -17.7353231,-63.1696634, Av. Block, NY00, Miami, United States
</address>
```

or

```
<address class="address address--tight">
    Av. Block, NY00, Miami, United States
</address>
```